# IBM Watson Conversation - Python: Make chat bot jump to some intent & get back to previous intent

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, chatbot, watson-conversation

I am working on a chat-box. I am using IBM Watson Conversation to make a conversation bot. My query is:

Suppose the user is talking to the bot in some specific node, and suddenly the user asks a random question, like "what is the weather?", my bot should be able to connect to few Internet websites, search the content and come with a relevant reply, and after that as the user inputs to get back to the previous topic, the bot should be able to resume from where it left.

**Summary:** How to code in **Python** to make the bot jump to some intent and
   then get back to previous intent. Thanks!

Comment: There are abundant of examples ion the net. This site requires you to make some attempt. Do your research first.,

Comment: Yes Mahendra I did indeed! What I am searching is for how to travel to a particular node via python code.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?! I am looking for something similar! @Pranzell I want to check if a simple if condition if some data is in a db, and if not, jump to the start node. If it is, keep it going!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for a "request response". This is a way to redirect the conversation / dialog flow to your app, and then forward it back to watson.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well let me clear my problem first:  Suppose I am currently in one node, and I want Watson to go to some particular node using 'response' code. Suppose I asked my bot, "What can you do?" The bot replies, "I can do XYZ". I confirm it, as "Sure, Go ahead, do XYZ". Then my bot asks me some information relating to XYZ. Then abruptly, I ask him, "Hey Bot, what is the weather now?"..... Now my bot should travel to Weather Intent, answer my query, and then when I input, "Hey, Lets get back to the topic", then my bot should be able to TRAVEL back to the previous node.

Comment: :My code in python right now is:                                                                 new_message = raw_input(prompt)   
 
 response=conversation.message(workspace_id=workspace_id, message_input ={'text':new_message},context=response['context'])

Comment: You don't code this in your python code, but in your dialog flow. ie. you dialog should be able to handle left field intents.